# Unable to use a computed default value in a combobox on a xpage

Tags: xpages

I want to use a comboBox to display several locations. All locations are stored in a view.
I want to have the default location to be displayed = location of the user in the person document in domino directory.
My problem is, the default value does not apply to the comboBox, but is correct if I display it in a computed field. If I hardcode a value as default it works.

Here is my code:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("UserLocation")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var sUserName:string=@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName());
var sServer:string=session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer();
if (sServer!=null)
{
var nDb:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(sServer,"names.nsf");
if (nDb!=null)
{
    var vUser:NotesView=nDb.getView("($VIMPeople)");
    if (vUser!=null)
    {
        var docUser:NotesDocument=vUser.getDocumentByKey(sUserName,true);
        if (docUser!=null)
        {
            var sLocation:string=docUser.getItemValue("Location");
                viewScope.put("UserLocation", sLocation);
        }
    }
}
}}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
    <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("UserLocation")}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(),"Standorte",1)}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>

</xp:comboBox>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox2" defaultValue="Hamburg">

    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbColumn(@DbName(),"Standorte",1)}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>

</xp:comboBox></xp:view>
```

The view Standorte has cities in the first column, sortet ascending: Berlin, Frankfurt, Hamburg,...
The value in the users Person document is Frankfurt.

Output in the browser is:
The computedfield1 displays Frankfurt (as expected)
the ComboBox1 displays Berlin (the first value - not the computed default)
the ComboBox2 displays Hamburg (as expected, because of hard coded default value)

Any suggestions what is wrong with the code?

Comment: I found the issue: 
var sLocation:string=docUser.getItemValue("Location");
viewScope.put("UserLocation", sLocation);

Puts a vector in the view scope.
When using getItemValueString, it works fine

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I would do to make this work:

First: Make sure the viewScope entry for UserLocation is a string not a vector. Use getItemValueString() instead of getItemValue();

```
if (docUser!=null) {
   var sLocation:string=docUser.getItemValueString("Location");
   viewScope.put("UserLocation", sLocation);
}
```

Second: Make sure the UserLocation is part of the combobox pick list even if it does not exist in the lookup:

```
var list = @DbColumn(@DbName(),"Standorte",1);
list.push(viewScope.get("UserCompany"));
return @Unique(list);
```

Finally I would also make sure the user is not "Anonymous" and perhaps trap the session.getDatabase() in case there is an access issue to names.nsf.

```
if(sUserName == "Anonymous") return;
try {
   var nDb:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(sServer,"names.nsf");
} catch(ex) {
   return;    // something went wrong opening the directory.    
}
```

Happy coding.

/Newbs

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

1. ssjs is case-sensitive.
2. Are both values from the names.nsf and from the view the same?
3. Use .trim on both values to be sure they are the same